# Symfony2 List rows in fields to update

Tags: php, symfony

I have table **options**, which have 2 fields (**name** and **value**) and 5 rows for example. I need to list all the rows in 5 fields on one page, so i can update every one of them.

[image]

I know i have to create collections, but i can't find simple example with functionality to view and update rows on one page.

First, i need to find all options rows.

```
    $options = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getRepository('ACMETestBundle:Option')
                   ->findAll();
```

What should i do next ? How can i list them in one form ? How can i update every value in database ?

Comment: Please see [Symfony2 - data from a form collection element ends up as arrays instead of Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6787671/367456).

Comment: every example that i find have one-to-many relationship.. and it's easy when you have that relationship.. i don't have any entity that sits on top of Options entity..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

You create an entity (it doesn't has to be an ORM entity), it will have an options member, which is an `ArrayCollection`. Create a form for this entity (http://sf.khepin.com/2011/08/finally-through-symfony2-forms-and-collectiontype-make-it-dynamic/).

In the controller you can pass the list of the options to the entity (`$entity->setOptions($options)`. Now you can render the form, and it will have the collection of the entities. After posting you can get the options (`$entity->getOptions()`) and save them individually.